# OWIN service can't be accessed across network

Tags: owin

Tried the following as per one suggestion;

```
   static void Main()
    {
        string url = "http://localhost:8080/";
        StartOptions options = new StartOptions(); 
        options.Urls.Add("http://localhost:8080"); 
        options.Urls.Add("http://127.0.0.1:8080"); 
        options.Urls.Add(string.Format("http://{0}:8080", Environment.MachineName)); 

        using (WebApp.Start<Startup>(options))
        {
          HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
          var response = client.GetAsync(url + "api/Values").Result;
          Console.WriteLine(response);
          Console.WriteLine(response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result);
          Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

Can connect with local browser, but remote machines get 'webpage is not available'.
Set reservation with 'add urlacl url=http://*:8080/ user=EVERYONE'
Port 8080 is open, tried many other ports with same results.

tried suggestion below, same result;

```
var options = new StartOptions("http://*:8080")
  {
     ServerFactory = "Microsoft.Owin.Host.HttpListener"
  };
```

Nothing is working remotely, only locally - is there anything else I can try?

Comment: Which Windows version you are trying to host your app on? (It took me a while to configure HTTP.sys on Windows Server 2003)